# Compilation error when passing a argument with :: to a macro invocation

Tags: rust

I was attempting a macro like following

```
from_converter!(std::io::Error, MyError);
```

```
macro_rules! from_converter {
    ($e: tt, $n: tt) => {
        impl std::convert::From<$e> for Error {
            fn from(source: $e) -> Self {
                $n.into_error(source)
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The compilation error I get is:

```
no rules expected the token `::`

no rules expected this token in macro callrustc
error.rs(37, 1): when calling this macro
error.rs(47, 20): no rules expected this token in macro call
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tt` is a TokenTree, which means a singular token. The first one (`$e`) should be a type, denoted as `ty`, and the second (`$n`) should be an expression, denoted as `expr`:

```rs
macro_rules! from_converter {
    ($e: ty, $n: expr) => { /* ... */ };
}
```